# validates uniqueness with scope is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

v3.2.1

**Not sure why 'count' is coming up nil and index won't render, as 'count' it's been fine in every model until I do the uniqueness with scope validation.**

**Any suggestions?**

---

**MODEL**

```
Class FeatureIcon < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :img_size, :feature_name, :image, :user_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :img_size, :scope => :feature_name

  //paperclip interpolates stuff....
end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
before_filter :load_user

def index
  @feature_icons = @user.feature_icons.all
  @feature_icon = @user.feature_icons.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @feature_icons }
    format.js
  end
end


def create
  @feature_icon = @user.feature_icons.new(params[:feature_icon])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @feature_icon.save
      format.html { redirect_to user_feature_icons_url, notice: 'successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @feature_icon, status: :created, location: @feature_icon }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render action: "index" }
      format.json { render json: @feature_icon.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**ERROR**

```
NoMethodError in Feature_icons#create

undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass
  Extracted source (around line #7):

  6:       <div class="count">
  7:         <div id="count" class="feed-count"><%= @feature_icons.count %></div>
  8:       </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `create` method, you instanciate `@feature_icons` (with an 's'), but in the view you're using `@feature_icon` (without the 's'), so `@feature_icons` is `nil`.

If the save fails, the line `format.html { render action: "index" }` renders the view `index.htm.erb`, but the method `index` in the controler is not not called. Try with

```
if @feature_icon.save
  #... nothing to change
else
  format.html do
    @feature_icons = @user.feature_icons.all
    render action: "index"
  end
  format.json { render json: @feature_icon.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

or

```
if @feature_icon.save
  #... nothing to change
else
  format.html { redirect_to :index }
  format.json { render json: @feature_icon.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
```